# How to make custom bbcode?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a custom bbcode with few tags: bold, italise, strike and underline just like that of whatsapp. Currently, i'm doing this but not perfect:

```
var bold=/\*(.*?)\*/gi
var italise=/_(.*?)_/gi

var data='**Bold this* and _italise this_';

data=data. replace(bold,function(m,text){
   return '<strong>' + text + '</strong>';
  }).replace(italise,function(m,text){
   return '<i>' + text + '</i>';
  });
```

This is not elegant and also doesn't bold text if there is * * Bold this * but this * Bold this * works

and i feel there will be too much replace thinking if i can achieve this using array and call replace once just like in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replace the function with a string, and use `$1` for the first captured group:

```js
var bold = /\*([^*]+)\*/gm
var italise = /_([^_]+)_/gm

var data = '*Bold this* and _italise this_'

data = data.replace(bold, '<b>$1</b>').replace(italise, '<i>$1</i>')

console.log(data)
document.write(data)
```

**Edit**: to get the effect you are looking for, you'll need to define a function for that.

```js
String.prototype.replaceMultiple = function () {
  let v = this;
  [...arguments].forEach(arg => (v = v.replace(arg[0], arg[1])));
  return v;
}

let str = '*Bold this* and _italise this_ and **strikethrough** another *bold*   **strikethrough2** and _italic!_'
let newStr = str.replaceMultiple(
  [/(?<!\*)\*([^*]+)\*(?!\*)/gm, '<b>$1</b>'], // Bold
  [/_([^_]+)_/gm, '<i>$1</i>'], // italic,
  [/\*\*([^*]+)\*\*/gm, '<s>$1</s>'] // strikethrough
)
console.log(str)
console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but is it possible to make use of just one replace() instead of replace().replace(). I mean like putting the regex in array, like data.replace( array, array);

Comment: @Theconcise, Edited my answer to contain the effect you want.

Comment: Great...Thank you...Accepted as answer.

Comment: Great...Thank you...Accepted as answer.